# Does display block and display none not supported in IE8?

Tags: html

I have used two images under a table row with id "bannerweb" for web/common and id "bannermobile" for mobile and tab compatibility.

```
     <tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <img src="http://campaign.vmware.com/imgs/apac/templates/20596_APAC_ASEAN_Bootcamp/images/Architect_Bootcamp_masthead1.jpg" id="bannerweb" width="700" height="189">
    <img src="http://images.connect.vmware.com/eloquaimages/clients/VMWare/{b28e5230-1543-4326-8ee8-a780172f2a75}_Architect_Bootcamp_masthead1_mobile.jpg"  id="bannermobile" />
    </td>
      </tr>

and the style applied as such,

     <style type="text/css">
```

For mobile compatibility,

```
     <!--Mobile-->
      @media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 361px) {
      #bannerweb{
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
    }
    #bannermobile{
    display:block;
    width:235px;
    }
       }
```

For tablet view,

```
      <!--Tablet-->
      @media screen and (min-width: 362px) and (max-width: 561px) {
      #bannerweb{
    display:block;
    width:500px;
    height:150px;
    }
    #bannermobile{
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
    }
      }
```

And this style is applied commonly for all web pages.

```
     <!--Common-->
     @media screen and (min-width: 562px) and (max-width: 2000px) {
     #bannerweb{
    display:block;
    }
    #bannermobile{
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
    }
     }
     </style>.
```

But in the above code is not reflected in IE 8 alone. display block and none doesny work in IE 8. Any soultions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using [RespondJs](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)?

IE8 doesn't support by default the media queries, that might be your problem